# NSExpression returns incorrect value

Tags: ios

I'm using NSExpression for doing some calculation but it retune incorrect value if the input value are large, say for example

e.g.,

```
NSString *equation = @"9999999999999 * 9999999999999"
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:equation]; //
id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]; //result is "-2537784290115403775"
```

If the equation would have been @"9 * 9" , then it return 18.
Why does it returns incorrect value, if the input is bigger.

Please correct me, if i've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because this is because your calculation results in a number that cannot be  stored in a 
 `64 bit data type`. A `64 bit` data type **signed int** datatype can only store numbers upto `-2^63` to `2^63-1` Your expression's result is obviously higher than the maximum limit.